# What, if anything, is a square radian?

Tags: geometry, circles, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

My 1st year Mathematics BSc course notes on circular motion use
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(\sin\theta)
&=\frac{d}{dt}(\sin(\omega t))\tag{1.1}\\
&=\omega\cos(\omega t),\tag{1.2}\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\sin\theta)
&=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\sin(\omega t))\tag{2.1}\\
&=\frac{d}{dt}(\omega\cos(\omega t))\tag{2.2}\\
&=-\omega^2\cos(\omega t),\tag{2.3}
\end{align}
where

- $\omega$ is angular speed, a scalar, with units $\text{rad}\cdot s^{-1}$;
- $t$ is time, a scalar, with units $s$.

From this it seems to me to follow that $\omega^2$ has units $(\text{rad}\cdot s^{-1})^2=\text{rad}^2\cdot s^{-2}$. Is that right, and, if so, does a square radian have a physical meaning?

Comment: I'll tell you once you give physical meaning to a square-second

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I can sort-of understand $s^{-2}$ as "per second per second". Is there an analogous way of interpreting $\text{rad}^2$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen brutal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"rad(ians)" is just another word for the number $1$, a unit-less unit. An angle is some part of a full rotation at $2\pi$, a unitless number. However, to tell that any number stands for an angle and not some amount of apples or cake, there is the habit to add "radians" to it.

Comment: I can see that a radian is a dimensionless fraction, but isn't its value $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ rather than $1$? In that case, does it follow that a square radian is a dimensionless fraction with value $(\frac{1}{2\pi})^2=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}$?

Comment: No, $1rad$ is the angle of $180/\pi=57.29577951308232$ degrees, "fraction of $2\pi$" is perhaps an unfortunate formulation. $\tau=2\pi$ radians is a full circle, so all unsmooth numbers which is the reason why the degree system still exists, all "main" "algebraic" angles  have nice degree numbers $k\cdot 3°$, $k=1,5,10,15,20,30$.

Comment: More directly, the angle subtended at a point is $2\pi$. A radian is $1/2\pi$ times that. $2\pi \times 1/2\pi = 1$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I have no problem with degree and radians being inter-convertible, given a suitable conversion factor. I understand a degree to be a dimensionless fraction with value $\frac{1}{360}$. We could equally use quarter-turns as our pseudo-unit. My knowledge of smooth numbers amounts to a glance at wikipedia just now, so that part may be lost on me for now.

Comment: I used "unsmooth" because "unround" numbers already have a definition as those not entirely made up of the "round" digits $3,6,8,9,0$. The "nice" angles have very irrational representations in radians.

Comment: @mjc The radian is equal to $1$ because angle is arc length over radius and a metre divided by a metre equals $1$: $\theta\ {\rm rad}=\dfrac{s\ \rm m}{r\ \rm m} = s/r\cdot1$. You don’t have to use metres though. Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

While a square radian is just radians squared in the context of the question, I was taught that just as a radian is a unit of "linear" angle, so a squaradian or steradian is a unit of [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle). The solid angle around a point is $4\pi$ steradians.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle

Comment: Thanks. I stole your link and added it to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

*OP answering own question*.

Remarks by Hagen von Eitzen and Lutz Lehmann have prompted me to think of the following answer.

A radian is a dimensionless fraction with value 
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}.$$

It seems to me to follow that a square radian is a dimensionless fraction with value 
$$\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)^2=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}.$$

This can be thought of as the angle by which the angular speed increases each second.

Comment: Not really, it is $\frac1{2\pi}$ of a full cycle around the unit circle, so 1rad is still equal to 1.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Do you mean a radian in a non-unit circle is different to a radian in a unit circle? My understanding is that a radian covers an arc length of $r$ on a circle of radius $r$, but always represents the same fraction of $\frac{r}{2\pi r}=\frac{1}{2\pi}$.

Comment: I'm not proposing a revolution, the analytical angle (measure) is the arc length of the sector on the unit circle under the geometrical angle. Or arc length divided by radius for any other circle.

Comment: "not proposing a revolution": nice pun. I know very little about measure theory, and haven't heard "analytical angle" and "geometrical angle" distinguished before. If analytical angle is arc length divided by radius, is geometrical angle arc length?

Comment: No, the geometrical angle is an object in Euclidean geometry, an equivalence class under shifts and rotations of ordered pairs of rays originating at the same point, or in other words, cones or wedges.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That's a very useful concept, thanks. I take it you use "rays" as opposed to "line segments" intentionally, to imply infinite outward length?

Comment: @mjc If you wanted to say that a radian is a dimensionless value that represents a fraction $1/2\pi$ of the full angle around a point, that's fine; but saying that a radian _has value_ $1/2\pi$ is just incorrect. 1 'radian' has value 1, and that's very relevant for things like $\sin(x)\approx x$.